# Checkers 2D array - Checkers not moving

Tags: java, awt

I'm programming Checkers and having an issue where my checkers aren't moving. I'm using a Java Applet. It registers the fact that I click, but it's not moving the checker itself.

Here's my MouseClicked, I think that's where I'm having the problem:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX=e.getX();
    mouseY=e.getY();
    col = (mouseX-115)/100;
    row = (mouseY-115)/100;

    if(board[row][col].getPlayer()==player)
    {   oldCol = col;
        oldRow = row;
        if(board[row][col].getPlayer()==0)
        {
            if(board[oldRow][oldCol].getPlayer()==1 && board[oldRow][oldCol].getKing()==false)
            {
                if(row==oldRow-1)
                {
                    if(col==oldCol-1 || col==oldCol+1)
                    {
                        board[oldRow][oldCol].setPlayer(0);
                        board[row][col].setPlayer(1);
                        board[row][col].setKing(false);
                    }
                }
            }    
            else if(board[oldRow][oldCol].getPlayer()==1 && board[oldRow][oldCol].getKing()==true)
            {
                if(row==oldRow-1 || row==oldRow+1)
                {
                    if(col==oldCol-1 || col==oldCol+1)
                    {
                        board[oldRow][oldCol].setPlayer(0);
                        board[row][col].setPlayer(1);
                        board[row][col].setKing(true);
                    }
                }
            }  
            else if(board[oldRow][oldCol].getPlayer()==2 && board[oldRow][oldCol].getKing()==true)
            {
                if(row==oldRow-1 || row==oldRow+1)
                {
                    if(col==oldCol-1 || col==oldCol+1)
                    {
                        board[oldRow][oldCol].setPlayer(0);
                        board[row][col].setPlayer(2);
                        board[row][col].setKing(true);
                    }
                }
            }  
            else if(board[oldRow][oldCol].getPlayer()==2 && board[oldRow][oldCol].getKing()==false)
            {
                if(row==oldRow+1)
                {
                    if(col==oldCol-1 || col==oldCol+1)
                    {
                        board[oldRow][oldCol].setPlayer(0);
                        board[row][col].setPlayer(2);
                        board[row][col].setKing(false);
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: I also put all of my logic in event handlers, it's the wave of the future. Don't let the naysayers dissuade you.

Comment: Refactor the code to eliminate the duplicates. And add some debug messages and you will figure out the issue.